# Blank icon on android notification when ticker is enabled

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have this code

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker("texto")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Notification n = builder.getNotification();
        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int notif_ref = 1;

        notifManager.notify(notif_ref, n);
```

But when the ticker is enabled I have a blank icon

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using a wrong size due to R.drawable.ic_launcher, you should use ad-hoc size for notification icons. In addition, you are out of design guidelines. The notification icons must be white and flat.

Comment: adding to what @greywolf82 says, in lollipop and up the OS forces notification icons to be white so it would appear like you see in the first image. Better stick to the guidelines

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @greywolf82 and @tycz says the issue is not using the corrects sizes. Thanks!

```
MDPI - 24 x 24  (drawable-mdpi)

HDPI - 36 x 36  (drawable-hdpi)

XHDPI - 48 x 48  (drawable-xhdpi)

XXHDPI - 72 x 72  (drawable-xxhdpi)

XXXHDPI - 96 x 96  (drawable-xxxhdpi)
```